# How to put the "build" module in python search path

Tags: python, linux

After so much of hassle i build the libxml [from source](http://lxml.de/build.html). I performed following steps

1. Downloaded the lxml.tar.gz and extracted its contents
2. Build it using

`python2.7 setup.py build_ext -i  -I /usr/include/libxml2 --with-xslt-config=/opt/xslt/bin/xslt-config`

1. I tried going in python shell and tried `import lxml` . it didn't worked
2. Then i went into directory

   `/home/user/tmp/(extracted lxml directory/`

and on linux command prompt i typed

```
PYTHONPATH=src python27
```

then i tried `import lxml` and then it worked.

`src` folder conatains folder name `lxml`

So i want to know that when i build the `lxml` does it mean that i always need that directory to use it or  i can delete that. If not then in which location do i need to put that folder so that if i run python normal way then i can access that

1. Does the modules which we build ourselves are not installed in python folder??
2. Can i make python egg from it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You told it to `build_ext`, so it just compiled it and didn't install. If you told it to `install`, it would install it in system-wide directory (but you need write permissions for that) or whatever directory you specify (with `--home` (for installing as user) or `--prefix` (for installing as root to non-standard directory like under `/opt`) option).

Comment: can i now just copy that folder in python/lib/site-packages or i need to install

Answer (score 0):

When you set `PYTHONPATH`, you gave it a relative path, so it will only work from that folder. If you specify an absolute path, like:

```
export PYTHONPATH=/home/user/tmp/extracted_whatever
```

It will work regardless of the folder you're in now.

Comment: Actually that is my temporary folder and i don't want to keep there. Where should i move it. Another question is when we build modules does it mean that we configure the module in the folder itself , we are not copying files to python folders like we normally do in make install. because then i never have to refer the current folder